# foreign key with 'no foreign key' value

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In my application I use MS SQL Server 2008 and Linq-to-SQL. I have two tables: `A` and `B`, linked with foreign key: `B.AId` => `A.Id`. Is it possible in `B.AId` to have a value, for instance `-1`, which means 'no A' and ignores foreign key?

I can't use `NULL` in `B.AId` because Linq-to-SQL does not correclty support one-to-oneorzero associations (unfortunately).

Comment: Why don't you "insert" a row in A with `id = -1` and have it's description as "no A"?

Comment: Because table `A` has a lot of columns, most of them are not nullable and can't have dummy values, also Linq-to-SQL generated class `A` is extended with a lot of functionality, which again is not designed to be dummy. Of course I can do it, but it will require a lot of extra work.

Comment: I have no experience in Linq-to-SQL, but the definition of FK says it has to *refer* the primary key in other table. So, I don't think it's possible without some clever hack. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Created a sample model with tables A and B

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AA] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AAA] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BB] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BBB] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[B]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_B_A] FOREIGN KEY([AId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[A] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[B] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_B_A]
GO
```

After that generated a model from database. Even though it is recognized as a 1 to many relationship a navigation property A is created for table B.

[image: Linq-to-sql model]

I created a test and created three different rows in table B

1. Using navigation property A
2. Using Id of A
3. Created a row without reference to A

   ```
   using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
   {
       // Add sample A row
       var sampleARow = new A()
                            {
                                Id = 1,
                                AA = "AA",
                                AAA = "AAA",
                            };

       db.As.InsertOnSubmit(sampleARow);
       db.SubmitChanges();

       // Refer to sample A row using navigation property
       var sampleNewBRowWithNav = new B()
                              {
                                  Id = 1,
                                  BB = "BB1",
                                  BBB = "BBB1",
                                  A = db.As.First(),
                              };

       // Refer to sample A row using Id
       var sampleNewBRowWithId = new B()
       {
           Id = 2,
           BB = "BB2",
           BBB = "BBB2",
           AId = 1,
       };

       // No reference to A
       var sampleNewBRowWithoutA = new B()
       {
           Id = 3,
           BB = "BB3",
           BBB = "BBB3",
           AId = null  // strictly not needed, because AId is default null
       };

       db.Bs.InsertOnSubmit(sampleNewBRowWithNav);
       db.Bs.InsertOnSubmit(sampleNewBRowWithId);
       db.Bs.InsertOnSubmit(sampleNewBRowWithoutA);

       db.SubmitChanges();
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for your efforts. Please declare `public enum AId { A = 1 }`, then change type of `A.Id` and `B.AId` from `int` to `AId`, then try again. Does it work?

Comment: I do not know what the effect will be of changing generated code. I will try.

Comment: Not generated code, but DBML code. In Property Editor please select `Id` property and change its type from `System.Int32` to `AId`.

Comment: Then try to `new B { Id = 4, AId = null }`. Unfortunately, due to nasty Linq-to-SQL bug it will not work. I am trying to find workaround of this problem.

Comment: Nope, same issue as you probably faced. A nullable navigation property  for column AId in table B is not generated.

Comment: Why do you introduce the enum? Your DBMS will make sure that you can not enter an invalid AId by the FK. Btw you can look at Entity Framework, which has definitely more possibilities.

Comment: Thank you very much - your work was very helpful. Unfortunately, you are absolutely right and now I know for sure: nullable navigation properties are not generated when I use enums instead of ints. If I manually change type of property from `AId` to `AId?` - it argues that properties have _different_ type and does not generate code at all. So I stuck here. I introduced enums because `Id` has some semantical meaning and it is quite elegant to write `.Where(Id == AId.Something)`.

Comment: what Visual Studio do you use? Because I tried newest version of SqlMetal and it generates valid code!

Comment: I created the example with VS2010 and used the designer. Great to hear that there is also a command line utility.